# Delete files without an extension in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to recursive delete all files which have no extension.

I already have the following command to delete files which have a specific extension:

`Remove-Item <PATH> -include *.tmp -force -recurse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "yourpath" -file -recurse | where {-not $_.extension} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Note: remove the -whatif to apply the action. `-file` will only list files and not folders

using the `include` in the `get-childitem` will restrict the scope to just that extension.

Answer (score -3):

Here's what worked for me:

```
Remove-Item C:\Test\*
```

Comment: How are you specifying the extension?

Comment: In this case I wasn't specifying an extension, but  you can just do *.fileextension

So, for example "Remove-Item C:\Test\*.txt"